# Store views in a buffer and show them later

Tags: java, android

I want to put views in something like a buffer and then show them later.
Something like:

```
public void addTextView(int belowId, int id,String text){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(id);

    tv.setText(text+"\n");

    ///i mean something like this:
    buffer = addview(tv,lp)

}
```

and later show it

```
public void showview(bufferview b){
        RelativeLayout rSub= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rSub);
        rsub.addview(b);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK if you do so it will eat up memory and will affect application performance.

Comment: Maybe you can use [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `Map`?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

```
Map<Integer,TextView> textViewMap = new HashMap<Integer,TextView>();

public void addTextView(int belowId, int id,String text){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setId(id);

    tv.setText(text+"\n");

    textViewMap.put(tv.getId(), tv);
}

public void showview(int id){
    RelativeLayout rSub= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rSub);
    rsub.addview(textViewMap.get(id));
}
```

Comment: it's not just text view!

Comment: I added the layoutparams to the textview `tv.setLayoutParams(lp)` which should accomplish what you are trying to do. If that's not enough of course you can create a more complicated data structure, in the standard OO way.